# C conflicting types for typedef struct

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I have a problem my C program. I am new C Programming. I coded something and here my error and warning.

```
[Warning] conflicting types for 'setFirstValuesForSample' [enabled by default]

[Error] previous implicit declaration of 'setFirstValuesForSample' was here
```

What am I missing when calling my function ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define MAX_TERIM_SAY 101
    #define KARSILASTIR(x,y) (((x)<(y))?-1:((x)==(y))?0:1)
    typedef struct{
        int sat;//satır bilgisi
        int kol;//sütun bilgisi
        int deger;
    } terim;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        terim a[MAX_TERIM_SAY],b[MAX_TERIM_SAY],c[MAX_TERIM_SAY];
        setFirstValuesForSample(a[MAX_TERIM_SAY],b[MAX_TERIM_SAY]);
        return 0;
    }
    void setFirstValuesForSample(terim a[],terim b[])
    {
        a[0].sat = 5;
        a[0].kol = 5;
        a[0].deger = 4;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setFirstValuesForSample` is not declared before it is used. Therefore it has an implicit declaration

```
int setFirstValuesForSample();
```

That doesn't match the definition,

```
void setFirstValuesForSample(terim a[],terim b[]) { ... }
```

You need to provide the right declaration before it is used in `main`:

```
void setFirstValuesForSample(terim a[], terim b[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

/* as before */
```

Next, when you actually call it in main,

```
setFirstValuesForSample(a[MAX_TERIM_SAY],b[MAX_TERIM_SAY]);
```

you are passing it two arguments of type `terim`. That doesn't match the definition either. You need to change the call to

```
setFirstValuesForSample(a, b);
```